# Explanation needed with strtotime() function, Can someone explain this line?

Tags: php

I am observing this code in a php file which is a strtotime function.  Please tell me the meaning of '-1-1' in the following function.

strtotime($year. '-1-1')

Comment: when result you want getting?

Comment: Will be literal - ... Jan/01, if the year is 2016 for example, will return the timestamp for 01/01/2016

Comment: Use strtotime() function for processing date. Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strtotime() converts your string of time into Unix timestamps.

eg:

```
strtotime("now") returns 1461336078
strtotime("3 October 2005") returns 1128312000
strtotime("+5 hours") returns 1461354078 and so on.
```

In your case, your string of time is "2016-1-1", if $year = 2016. That is to say, strtotime($year.'-1-1'); will returns the timestamps of first day of any year you supplied in $year variable by simply concatenating your year with '-1-1'.

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could upvote it. It was really helpful. I was stuck on this since an hour.

Answer (score 0):

It's the month and day of the date concatenated onto the end of whatever $year is..

if $year = 2016, it's the same as writing `strtotime('2016-1-1');`